# Cannot read property "Name" of undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6, axios

I'm experiencing something bizarre or maybe I just missed something? I'll walk you through the codebase:

Annex 1.1 We are using react useState and useEffect hooks to update our state when pulling data from the API. `resCrypto.data.Data[0]` returns a single object with different properties

```
function Financeticker() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [crypto, setCrypto] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totalvolfull?limit=10&tsym=USD&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
            )
            .then((resCrypto) => {
                console.log(resCrypto.data.Data[0]);
                setCrypto(resCrypto.data.Data[0]);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);
```

Annex 1.2 `const cryptoTicker` is a variable within the component that contains the contents of what I'm going to render. The problem is when I call `{crypto.CoinInfo.Name}` I get Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined.

```
const cryptoTicker = (
        <Grid item container xs={2}>
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography
                        className={classes.companyName}
                        color='textSecondary'
                        gutterBottom
                    >
                        {crypto.CoinInfo.Name}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    );
```

However when I reorder the `setCrypto` argument to be  `setCrypto(resCrypto.data.Data[0].CoinInfo.Name);` and just call the `{crypto}` state instead then it works fine. What am I doing wrong? I'd like the argument for `SetCrypto` to be `(resCrypto.data.Data[0])` instead of being too specific since I will be calling other properties from the API object.

Annex 1.3 (optional) This is just the return method of the child component. I added it here for context. Basically, it just calls `{cryptoTicker}` within a grid component from material-ui.

```
return (
        <Grid container direction='column'>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Ticker speed={2} mode='chain'>
                    {() => <>{cryptoTicker}</>}
                </Ticker>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}

export default Financeticker;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the 1st render, before the async call is made, and the state updated.

Since `crypto` and `CoinInfo` are objects, use optional chaining to get `Name`.

Calling `{crypto?.CoinInfo?.Name}` would get you `undefined` on the 1st render, and the value of `Name` after the call is done.

You should not initialize the state with an empty array (`[]`), because that's not the value you are expecting. This should be enough:

```
const [crypto, setCrypto] = useState();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, oh yeah. it's because I was rendering an array. I didn't know going from `([])` to `()` could be so detrimental. Thanks again :)

Comment: Also I didn't know about optional chaining until now. I still got a lot of ground to cover in react. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: You're welcome. The problem is not the array. Arrays are objects as well, but `[].CoinInfo` is `undefined`. It's just a needless init, that might be confusing in the future.